# Ruby pattern matching when making a system call in linux

Tags: ruby, regex, linux

Got stuck with a bit of code. I've researched a way to return true if my system call result matches a phrase set in a variable. I've tried a few things like converting the system call to string. Also, here's what I've tried so far:

```
def pattern_test
  test = system('rpm -q --queryformat "%{SUMMARY}\n" some-package | grep -o "String I Want To Match"')
  word = /String I Want To Match/i
  puts test === word ? "True" : "False"
end
pattern_test

def pattern_test2
  test2 = system('rpm -q --queryformat "%{SUMMARY}\n" some-package | grep -o "String I Want To Match"')
  word2 = "String I Want To Match"
  puts test2 =~ word2 ? "True2" : "False2"
end
pattern_test2

def pattern_test3
  test3 = system('rpm -q --queryformat "%{SUMMARY}\n" some-package | grep -o "String I Want To Match"')
  word3 = "String I Want To Match"
  puts test3 =~ word3 ? "True3" : "False3"
end
pattern_test3

def pattern_test4
  test4 = system('rpm -q --queryformat "%{SUMMARY}\n" some-package | grep -o "String I Want To Match"').to_s
  word4 = "String I Want To Match"
  puts test4 === word4 ? "True4" : "False4"
end
pattern_test4
```

The result:

```
String I Want To Match
False
String I Want To Match
False2
String I Want To Match
False3
String I Want To Match
False4
```

My expected result would be a return of true since test and word match.

**Update**

I tried a few suggestions but they don't work either. Here are some more methods I've tried:
def pattern_test

```
test = `rpm -q --queryformat "%{SUMMARY}\n" some-package | grep -o "String I Want To Match"`
  word = /String I Want To Match/i
  puts test === word ? "True" : "False"
end
pattern_test

def pattern_test2
  test2 = %x(rpm -q --queryformat "%{SUMMARY}\n" some-package | grep -o "String I Want To Match")
  word2 = 'String I Want To Match'
  puts test2 === word2 ? "True" : "False"
end
pattern_test2

def pattern_test3
  test3 = IO.popen('rpm -q --queryformat "%{SUMMARY}\n" some-package | grep -o "String I Want To Match"')
  word3 = "String I Want To Match"
  puts test3 === word3 ? "True" : "False"
end
pattern_test3

def pattern_test4
  test4 = system('rpm -q --queryformat "%{SUMMARY}\n" some-package | grep -o "String I Want To Match"')
  word4 = 'String I Want To Match'
  puts test4 === word4 ? "True" : "False"
end
pattern_test4
```

And this is the output:

```
False
False
False
String I Want To Match
False
```

**Update2**

I forgot to test one more thing per comments. This works but I'm not sure it's the best way to proceed:

```
def pattern_test
  test = system('rpm -q --queryformat "%{SUMMARY}\n" some-package | grep -o "String I Want To Match"')
  puts test4 == true ? "True" : "False"
end
pattern_test
```

Comment: Isn't the return value of system() the exit status of the program ? So maybe  test == 0 ? true : false;

Comment: I think if you use _bacticks_ instead of _system()_ you'd get the stdout of the command.

Comment: "system returns true if the command gives zero exit status, false for non zero exit status. Returns nil if command execution fails." https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system. Backticks, `%x(...)`, or one of the `popen` or `Open3` commands would be more like what you want.